# What does ${VISUAL} do in snippets?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

What is the difference between them?

With ${VISUAL} :

```
snippet if "if ... then (if)" b
if [[ ${1:condition} ]]; then
    ${0:${VISUAL}}
fi
endsnippet
```

Without ${VISUAL} :

```
snippet if "if ... then (if)" b
if [[ ${1:condition} ]]; then
    ${0}
fi
endsnippet
```

Comment: It's to be used with a visual selection. BTW, it would be good to mention which plugins  you are using (in this case, Ultisnips)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `:h UltiSnips-visual-placeholder`,

> Snippets can contain a special placeholder called ${VISUAL}. The ${VISUAL}
> variable is expanded with the text selected just prior to expanding the
> snippet.

To illustrate with your snippet above with `${VISUAL}`, a use case would be to surround a block of code with `if ... fi`. To do so, first visually select the block of code. Then hit `<tab>`, followed by `if<tab>`. The result is

```
if [[ |condition| ]]; then
    block of code
fi
```

where `condition` is now selected.

Without `${VISUAL}`, the block of code would be missing:

```
if [[ |condition| ]]; then

fi
```